# jQuery Slide in and out behaving odd, buttons disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a mockup and have created this:
http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/

I'm having a problem with my nav buttons: Play, About, How To.

If you click 'about' then 'how to' everything works fine, but if you go from 'how to' to 'about' the 'how to' disappears. How do I get all the buttons to work consistently and not disappear. Also I am noticing the slide transitions are actign a little funny, sometimes displaying a white banner.

I want the jquery to be just inside the content area but its appears to flash quickly above and over the footer.

Can anyone shed some light?

Here are some snippets of my code:

CSS:

```
#contentArea{
    width:1024px;
    height:522px;
    background:#FFF;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#playSlide, #howSlide, #aboutSlide {
    display: none
}

.toggleDiv p {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toggleDiv" id="aboutSlide">
    <div class="navContainer">
    <div class="menuItem">
        <a class="show_hide" rel="#playSlide">
            <img src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/play_black.png" onMouseOver=src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/play.png" onMouseOut=src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/play_black.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
        <a class="show_hide" rel="#aboutSlide">
            <img src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/about_btn_hover.png" onMouseOver=src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/about_btn_hover.png" onMouseOut=src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/about_btn.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
        <a class="show_hide" rel="#howSlide">
            <img src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/howtoplay_btn.png" onMouseOver=src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/howtoplay_btn_hover.png" onMouseOut=src="http://cynthialarenas.billybluedigital.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/howtoplay_btn.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using images for your navigation, that's horrible for SEO. The reason your "How to" button is disappearing is because the image isn't being loaded so there's nothing to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna have to agree with Mitchell on this one. Using images for simple navigation like this is incredibly non-SEO friendly. Not only that, it's just plain unprofessional.

While I can't cause the problem to happen when I visit your site, I can offer an alternative to the images you're using.

http://jsfiddle.net/L2MVu/1

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">play</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">how to play</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, it's all editable, but still just as clean as you wanted from the images.

While this doesn't do a whole lot to save page-load time, it's always best to try to get a desired effect with pure CSS before resorting to images.